# New to Ubuntu 18.04, unable to install python3-dev

Tags: apt, 18.04, python, python3

I am actually in the process of trying to install a GitHub project via PyPI. I'm having some difficulty getting it to install so someone recommended that I try `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`

When I run that, I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies: python3-dev : 
Depends: libpython3-dev (= 3.6.5-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: python3.6-dev (>= 3.6.5-2~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I was using 16.04 I believe I used a Deadsnakes PPA so that might be causing this issue but I am completey unsure.